# How to update a list in a for loop(cannot store ggplot object into the list)

Tags: r, list, loops, ggplot2

```
plotss = list()
for (i in 1:6){
  plotss[[i]] <- qplot(x=total[,7], y= total[,names(total)[i]],geom = 'line')
}
```

I found all the 6 components in the list plotss are actually the plotss[[6]], which means the i=6 totally replace the previous all 5 components. Can anyone please help with it? 
Thanks a lot~

Comment: Maybe you should tag it with the programming language to find someone who can help you.

Comment: Thank you and let me add some tags now^_-